# Android text view size to 1280 pixels

Tags: android, textview

When I set layout_height in android to 1280 pixels , then my text view is being extended out of the screen although nexus 4's resolutions are 1280*768 .

Answer (score 2):

The Nexus 4 has a pixel density of xhdpi, so the 1280 pixel x 768 pixel physical display is a 640dp x 384dp scale in terms of android layout "device independent pixels".  If you set your layout to 1280dp x 768dp, this isn't correct.

Please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension for more information on screen density, device independent pixels (dp's).

If you're really just interested in *measuring* these sizes, after your Activity has loaded and layout has finished, you can call getWidth() and getHeight() on your view(s) of interest to determine their size after layout.

You will also want to know:

```
float pixelDensity = myContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

You can determine your *display* size:

```
WindowManager w = myActivity.getWindowManager();
Display display = w.getDefaultDisplay();
int height = display.getHeight();
int width = display.getWidth();
```

then:

```
int heightInDIPs = height / pixelDensity;
int widthInDIPs = width / pixelDensity;
```

The link Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes provided by @SpacePope  is best ... you can get some general guidelines for device sizes for each display category (small, medium, large, xlarge), and be sure to create graphics for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and now xxhdpi densities, and let the platform scale when necessary.

Comment: No i am setting it to 1280 px and still its going out of the screen ?

Comment: I want to know the value of match_parent of height in nexus 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "px" in your layout XML; "dp" is preferred to maintain scale across devices. Read up on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence).

Comment: Also, don't forget about things like the navigation bar/status bar that take up screen real estate; having a 1280x768 resolution isn't a guarantee that your app will have that many pixels to work with.

Comment: I want to know the value which i should set to cover full screen.

Comment: The proper way to do that is to use `fill_parent`; you don't want to hard-code those values in terms of pixels, lest your app only look right on one or two specific devices. See the "Best practices" section of the link I posted.

Comment: I know that but i want to know those values so that i am able to create images of that size and all the other designing stuff.